# Why jiffies protected by seq-lock but not directly use atomic operation

Tags: linux-kernel

Why jiffies protected by seq-lock but not directly use atomic operation?

Answer (score 0):

seq-lock doesn't block the writer, which for the jiffie counter is time sensitive.  The reader also doesn't block, just loops until the read succeeds.

An atomic increment is a read-modify-write, so the writer has to use a mechanism like CAS.

Answer (score 0):

`jiffies_64`, being a 64-bit value, may not be atomic to read and/or write on all architectures without the use of expensive "lock" instruction prefixes. Reading the trailing portion (`jiffies`) that is as big as the CPU's common word and register size however, is sufficiently atomic.